# Calling and assigning functions in JS without parenthesis

Tags: javascript, function, invocation

```
function makeFunc() {
  var name = "Mozilla";

  function displayName() {
    alert(name);
  }
  return displayName;
}

var myFunc = makeFunc();
myFunc();
```

The above code works even though displayName is without parentheses i.e. passing a reference to displayName which then would be invoked by makeFunc().

Now if you do `return displayName(); var myFunc = makeFunc;` It also works as expected. But if you do `return displayName; var myFunc = makeFunc;` it stops working.

It should've worked as those both functions would've been invoked by myFunc()?

Comment: If you use that third variation you need to do `myFunc()()`.`myFunc` is the same as `makeFunc` now, and as you can see from your own implementation, `makeFunc` just makes a function, it doesn't actually invoke it.

Comment: when you add parentheses, a function executes when you dont it just returns it

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin, awesome! Why does it work that way?

Comment: @MarinaDunst Well, as I said: `myFunc` is the same as `makeFunc` in your third variation. `makeFunc` returns a function when invoked. So invoking `myFunc` by doing `myFunc()` produces the `displayName` function, which you again need to invoke. Hence `myFunc()()`.

Comment: So when I do myFunc()() is equal to displayName() + makeFunc() ?

Comment: Perhaps this will clarify? `var innerFunction = myFunc(); innerFunction();` Remember that `makeFunc` *returns* the `displayName` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function reference is just a value in JavaScript. A function *call* is an expression involving two things: a reference to a function, and a parenthesized argument list.

Without an argument list, a reference to a function is just a value.

Thus, in your code:

```
function makeFunc() {
  var name = "Mozilla";

  function displayName() {
    alert(name);
  }
  return displayName;
}
```

the identifier "displayName" in the function refers to that inner function. The `return` statement references that identifier *without* a parenthesized argument list. Thus, the return value from `makeFunc()` is a reference to that inner function. Assigning that to another variable gives that variable the same value, so then it can be used in a function call expression later.

Note that you can call `makeFunc()` and call the returned function immediately:

```
makeFunc()();
```

That's a sequence of *two* function call expressions. The first is `makeFunc()`. That returns a function reference, so that function is called because of the second `()`.